# Redis, how to search by value in a sorted set?

Tags: redis, sortedset

I have a sorted list like the below:
"id" "{"date":1664353365563}"

So I need to delete from the sorted list when date is lass than today.

How to do such scenario?

I tried zrem but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can [ZREMRANGEBYSCORE](https://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyscore/). The command would be:

```
redis> ZREMRANGEBYSCORE id 0 1664353365563
```

Replace `1664353365563` with the timestamp for yesterday.

Comment: in my scenario, I have the score as 
SalesReps "Guid1"  "{\"date\":1664353365563,\"shopper\":\"#4544\",\"location\":\"france\",\"target\":0,\"isVip\":true}" 
"Guid2"  "{\"date\":1664353365563,\"shopper\":\"#4577\",\"location\":\"france\",\"target\":2,\"isVip\":false}" 
and so on.. I have 30M rows in this sorted list. I need a way to delete maybe 1000 by 1000, based on the date in the value.
So I don't want to delete based on the score, but based on the date inside the value.
is it feasible with StackExchange or any script in redis?

Comment: That's not a [Sorted Set](https://redis.io/commands/?group=sorted-set). Are you just storing JSON in a Hash in Redis? Or are you using RedisJSON or something like that?

Comment: it is a sorted list having as value a json containing many fields @GuyRoyse

Comment: to clarify,, I am storing a json inside the value

Comment: Redis doesn't have a sorted list type. It has [Lists](https://redis.io/commands/?group=list)—which are doubly-linked lists that stores [Strings](https://redis.io/commands/?group=string), [Sets](https://redis.io/commands/?group=set)—which are unordered and unduplicated collections of [Strings](https://redis.io/commands/?group=string), and [Sorted Sets](https://redis.io/commands/?group=sorted-set)—which are the same as a regular Set but also have a numeric score associate with them in addition to the [Strings](https://redis.io/commands/?group=string).